# Laravel - I Auth::user() in Authenticate.php Middleware return null

Tags: php, laravel, null, middleware

When I am trying to return Auth::user() or return $request->user(), the handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) function (in Authenticate.php middleware) returns null. This middleware execute for every route. I am trying to return Auth::user() because i need an email of currently logged user and returning Auth::user() is for checking if I can get informations about currently logged user.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        return Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: return `Auth::user()` ?  Return it to where?

Comment: I am trying to return it in postman

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is the default guard?

Comment: 'guards' => [
        // 'web' => [
        //     'driver' => 'session',
        //     'provider' => 'users',
        // ],

        'api' => [
                'driver' => 'jwt',
                'provider' => 'users',
        ],

    ],

Comment: what is the default set as? an please add this information to your answer in a code block not in the comments

Answer (score 1):

The `handle()` method in the parent class `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` performs the actual authentication. Since you've overridden this method and not calling the auth logic, authentication isn't performed and thus `Auth::user()` returns null.

You can remove the `handle()` method from your middleware, and add the debug-line `return Auth::user();` in `redirectTo()` instead (just before the `if()`).